# gcloud beta compute disks create example-disk --csek-key-file example-file.json” is failing

Tags: gcloud

When I am running the command "gcloud beta compute disks create example-disk --csek-key-file example-file.json" to create the encrypted disk using CSEK, it fails with the following error:

ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.disks.create) Key required for resource [https://www
.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/extreme-axon-162911/zones/us-east1-b/disks
/example-disk], but none found.
Please help me to find out the reason for failure.

Comment: Looks like the issue is that example-file.json doesn't have an encryption key for the disk you're trying to create. What're the contents of example-file.json (with the key material redacted, of course)?

Answer (score 1):

In order to resolve the issue, you will need to specify a valid value for `uri`. In JSON file, replace `myproject` with your real project ID, replace `v1` with `beta` since you're using `gcloud beta` command and also make sure the zone match to the zone that you're specifying with `gcloud` command.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the contents of json file. It has the key and I can able to create the disk when I am providing the key value in console but not using gcloud.

---

[
  {
  "uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/zones/us-central1-a/disks/example-disk",
  "key": "dkZCh83h78PlJ6z+fzjcm+ghgjklfVzzQtDCi3lO1qG5MbUDug4TYQl77XTktmNOjF26UuH53pRRSgpSoXbh5Pft/U/Eja781OPpBiyZ6Apd1RvD01J97nWtpnyFNNq7EZl5a/GJ7vOPrD1dilzEdkokRW4exnmFJiR9Q8E5qDTdydOo11yyFme/H6Q4ikB2xD0c/0xqP0qn2L0NxP38HBR68bmj7QhlW3MLPlQZ8XxkA6THckEPatuYemb9Q3FIcevi5KsWKCa+BOX5uBgU0wgwcPI7MpOV5OOePL1t9lE8fB4vdZp9ILgrtxOxEdHhYmZtb0vQBTJ0MFzcdL6ZG6A==",
  "key-type": "rsa-encrypted"
  }

### ]